# Output in Reference variable in c++

Tags: c++, reference, pass-by-reference

I was learning about reference variables in c++.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int &fun()
{
    static int z = 10;  
    return z;
}                       
int main()
{                                      
    int x = fun();
    cout<<fun()<<endl;
    x = 30;
    cout<<fun();
    return 0;
}
```

Why this code is giving 10 10 instead to 10 and 30.

Comment: Explain why you expect 30 as the second output?

Comment: `x` isn't a reference?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Since the function is returning reference and we are changing it to 30. So z should be 30.

Comment: @Alan Birtles why?

Comment: You haven't declared it as a reference

Comment: Learn using a Debugger. It will help you in your further learning of the language and improve writing good code.

Answer (score 1):

`fun` returns a reference to `z` which is 10.

Your code is basically equivalent to this:

```
int *fun()
{
    static int z = 10;  
    return &z;
}                       
int main()
{                                      
    int x = *fun();
    cout << *fun() << endl;
    x = 30;
    cout << *fun();
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to get the behaviour you expect you need to declare `x` as a reference too:

```
int & x = fun();
```

This illustrates it:

```
using namespace std;
int & fun()
{
  static int z = 10;
  cout << "z = " << z << endl;
  return z;
}
int main()
{
  int & x = fun();
  cout << fun() << endl;
  x = 30;
  cout << fun();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the variable 'x' is not reference to 'z'

variable 'x' is an int and fun() returns an int&, 'z' only copies the value in 'x'

If you want to change the value of 'x' in fun(), you can:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int &fun()
{
    static int z = 10;  
    return z;
}                       
int main()
{                
    //X is a reference to Z          
    int& x = fun(); // auto x = fun();
    cout<<fun()<<endl;
    x = 30;
    cout<<fun();
    return 0;
}
```

or

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int &fun()
{
    static int z = 10;  
    return z;
}                       
int main()
{                                      
    int x = fun();
    cout<<fun()<<endl;
    //x = 30;
    //Fun directly returns a reference to Z
    fun() = 30;
    cout<<fun();
    return 0;
}
```